# Can i use xslt to display drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, css, xml, xslt

Hi I have this done using xml, php and css for styling.

But is it possible to have information in an xml file.  And use xslt to display the information in a table. I have a PHP and javascript file as well.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<TT>

<BUS>
<NUMBER>120</NUMBER>    
<LEAVING>Howth</LEAVING>
<DESTINATION>Dublin Airport</DESTINATION>
<TIME>06:00, 07:00, 08:10, 9:10, 10:00,
11:25, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:20, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00</TIME>
</BUS>
</TT>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$id=$_GET['q'];
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( 'routes.xml' );

$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('NUMBER');

if( $col ){
foreach( $col as $node ){


if( $node->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE && $node->nodeValue==$id ) {
$parent=$node->parentNode;
}
}


$html=array();
$html[]='
</br>

<table border="2">

 <tr>
 <th>NUMBER</th>
 <th>LEAVING</th>
 <th>DESTINATION</th>
 <th>TIME</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>';

 foreach( $parent->childNodes as $node ){
 if( $node->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE ) $html[]='<td>'.$node-           >nodeValue.'</td>';
 }

 $html[]='</tr><tr background-color: #f2f2f2></table>';
 echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
 }  


 ?>
```

JavaScript

```
function showBus(str){
if (str==""){
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {  // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","getbus.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<form>
<h3>Select your bus route:</h3>
<select name="NUMBER" onchange="showBus(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a Bus:</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="37">37</option>
<option value="44">44</option>
<option value="120">120</option>
</select>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Bus info will be listed here...</b></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to display the xml data with each BUS Number in the menu, when you click on the number the information such as destination time is displayed in a table, but i want it using xslt not html.

Comment: You can use the Saxon/CE library, and there will be zero PHP code to write. Take a look at http://www.saxonica.com/ce/demos/books/books.html .

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it can all be done using XSLT rather than PHP, it's a bit more involved but it can be done. I still have the original XSL file you posted with the original question and have modified it slightly here.

### routes.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <!-- we want to output html -->
        <xsl:output method='html' standalone='yes' indent='yes' encoding='utf-8'/>
        <!-- this is the important bit, the bus number ~ id -->
        <xsl:param name="id">id</xsl:param>

        <xsl:template match="/">
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>NUMBER</th>
                <th>LEAVING</th>
                <th>DESTINATION</th>
                <th>TIME</th>
              </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="TT/BUS">
                <xsl:choose><!-- perform a test using the supplied id param -->
                    <xsl:when test="NUMBER=$id">
                      <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="LEAVING"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="DESTINATION"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="TIME"/></td>
                       </tr>
                    </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

### getbus.php

```
<?php

    $id=$_GET['q'];
    /* Create DOMDocument for the xml */
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->load( __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'routes.xml' );

    /* Create the xslt processor & import stylesheet */
    $proc=new XSLTProcessor();
    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load( __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'routes.xsl' );

    $proc->importStyleSheet( $xsl );

    /* ! set the parameter to use in the stylesheet ! */
    $proc->setParameter('', 'id', $id );

    /* Transform the xml and display result */
    if( $html = $proc->transformToXML( $dom ) ){ echo $html; }

    /* tidy up */
    $dom = $xsl = $proc = $html = null;
?>
```

### To allow user to add a route

You need a form, you need to be able to identify the user, you need to have a location to store the generated xml files and probably a whole heap of other things too. So, very quickly:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Generate xml for Bus Route</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='usrxml' method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='number' placeholder='Bus number' />
            <input type='text' name='depart' placeholder='Departing from' />
            <input type='text' name='destination' placeholder='Travelling to' />
            <input type='text' name='times' placeholder='Times of travel' />

            <input type='submit' value='Create xml' />
        </form>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

                /* username??? */
                $username='fred.bloggs';
                $filename=__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$username.'bus_route.xml';

                $number         =   $_POST['number'];
                $depart         =   $_POST['depart'];
                $destination    =   $_POST['destination'];
                $times          =   $_POST['times'];

                $dom=new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8' );
                $root=$dom->appendChild( $dom->createElement('TT') );
                $bus=$root->appendChild( $dom->createElement('BUS') );


                $bus->appendChild( $dom->createElement('NUMBER', $number ) );
                $bus->appendChild( $dom->createElement('LEAVING', $depart ) );
                $bus->appendChild( $dom->createElement('DESTINATION', $destination ) );
                $bus->appendChild( $dom->createElement('TIME', $times ) );

                $dom->save( $filename );

                echo 'Route added to: '.$filename;
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm just wondering if its possible to allow a user to write their own bus routes, for it to save in a xml file and then it to display in the dropdown menu

Comment: yes, that would be possible - though you'd need to plan it out quite carefully ( a unique xml file for each user, making sure no nasty surprises make their way into the equation anywhere because as we all know you can't trust user input etc )

Comment: Would you be able to guide me on how to do it,.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a pure XSLT solution without PHP. It uses no PHP, no JavaScript (except linking to an off-the-self library). It is pure Html, CSS and XSLT 2.0.**

Given this **input document**, located with relative URL, `buses.xml` ...

```
<TT>
<BUS>
<NUMBER>120</NUMBER>    
<LEAVING>Howth</LEAVING>
<DESTINATION>Dublin Airport</DESTINATION>
<TIME>06:00, 07:00, 08:10, 9:10, 10:00,
11:25, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:20, 16:00, 17:00, 18:00</TIME>
</BUS>

<BUS>
<NUMBER>200</NUMBER>    
<LEAVING>Sydney</LEAVING>
<DESTINATION>Melbourne</DESTINATION>
<TIME>06:01, 07:01, 08:11, 9:11, 10:01,
11:25, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:20, 16:00, 17:01</TIME>
</BUS>    
</TT>
```

**... the interactive bus time-tables can viewed by this host page, with URL ...**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bus time-tables</title>
  <link href="buses.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">  
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/Saxonce/Saxonce.nocache.js"></script> 
  <script type="application/xslt+xml" language="xslt2.0" src="buses.xsl" data-source="buses.xml"></script>  
</head>

<body>
<form>
  <h3>Select your bus route:</h3> 
  <div id="bus-options"></div>    
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Bus number</th>
      <th>Departing from</th>
      <th>Arriving at</th>
      <th>Schedule</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="bus-rows"></tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**... which when loaded by the browser, leverages XSLT 2.0 stylesheet located at url `buses.xsl`...**

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ixsl="http://saxonica.com/ns/interactiveXSLT"
    xmlns:prop="http://saxonica.com/ns/html-property"
    xmlns:style="http://saxonica.com/ns/html-style-property"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs prop"
    extension-element-prefixes="ixsl"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">       
  <xsl:result-document href="#bus-options" method="ixsl:replace-content">
    <select name="NUMBER">      
      <option value="">Select a Bus:</option>    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="TT/BUS" mode="bus-option" />
    </select>    
  </xsl:result-document>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BUS" mode="bus-option">
    <option value="{NUMBER}"><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/></option>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="select[@name='NUMBER']" mode="ixsl:onclick">
  <xsl:variable name="bus" select="@prop:value"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="ixsl:source()/TT/BUS[NUMBER eq $bus]">    
    <xsl:result-document href="#bus-rows" method="ixsl:replace-content">
     <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="$bus"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="LEAVING"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="DESTINATION"/></td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(TIME,',')">
            <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>      
          </xsl:for-each>      
        </ul>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>      
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

A **CSS stylesheet** is required at relative url `buses.css`. I used this content, but it is not important. ...

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  background: hsl(150, 50%, 50%);
}
```

And the final **resource required is the [Saxon/CE library](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml)**. The resource should be placed at relative url `js/Saxonce/Saxonce.nocache.js`.

### The outcome

This is the perfect solution. The body of the table dynamically changes to match the user selection of bus. There are no call-backs. All switching is done on the client side, so performance scales very well. Data, html structure, visual styling, and business rules are neatly segregated into separate files. A user can write their own bus routes and save it in the xml file. The whole solution is small and simple.